# What is a graph with vertices randomly active called?

Tags: random, graph, graph-theory

I am talking about a graph , which has a fixed number of vertices. However, the vertices each have a probability of being active and inactive. While active , the edges from that vertex to other alive vertices are existent. What is this graph called?

I know that this is not exactly the random graph. In a random graph, the vertices are assumed to be in active state all the time, while the edges are existent with some probability p.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure do I understand question correctly.

Set of active vertices induces a [subgraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs).

If probabilities define some 'process', than it looks like [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), except in MC probabilities are on edges. It can be converted to Markov chain by replacing undirected edge with 2 directed edges whose probabilities are of incoming vertex and then normalized by outgoing vertex. This looks strange and I don't see application for it :-)